# Canon Pixma MP640 wireless network on Ubuntu 17.10 (64bit)

Tags: drivers, printing, 17.10, canon, pixma

Has anyone managed to run old Canon Pixma MP640 printer on Ubuntu 17.10?
Or do you have any idea how I could achieve this?

Original drivers from Canon are no longer available (and they were available for 32bit linux only).

I tried using Ubuntu's built in "Printers" configuration tool but with no success. It shows only CUPS-BRF-Printer when I open it. I tried to locate my printer by it's IP but it didn't work. When I install something like "Canon MP640 - CUPS+Gutenprint" it doesn't solve the issue.

I tried also ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk but it has no files for artful :-(

So I have no more ideas... 
Printer is fine and visible for sure - tested from Windows.

Comment: as well as the answer, have a read at post #10 here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384843 I think Kurt has a very good point:  releases such as 17.10 are new; innovative; and may have problems; LTS releases are for stability; various newer Canon (laser) printers have not worked with 17.10 but Canon have released a UFR driver a week ago that works for 17.10

Answer (score 0):

so the drivers are available: http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100236602.html coming down as cnijfilter-mp640series-3.20-1-i386-deb.tar.gz and 32bit;

If you do symbolic links, I wonder if that helps

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64

sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64
```

that is a 10 yr old printer; you are doing well to keep it going; and Canon do well to build such long-lasting hardware!!

from here, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2021854 is the justification for the links; perhaps do them first, and then download and install the drivers; from the earlier link;

it has an install script so

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mp640series-3.20-1-i386-deb.tar.gz

cd cnijfilter-mp640series-3.20-1-i386-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

and the terminal should ask you some questions as the script runs ..